# Confusion over the use of いい人

Tags: meaning

The scenario is a group of friends trying to figure out what to eat. One person says:
決を採ります！　洋食焼き[どど]がいい人ー？！

Friends respond: はあーい

He then says: 次に和食定食[めんぼう]がいい人ー！

Response: はあーい

I feel like I'm overthinking this but are (どど) and (めんぼう) supposed to be the names of eateries, and if so why use いい人 to describe something that isn't a person? If someone could enlighten me I would appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: What is 洋食焼き?  Makes no sense.

Comment: @l'électeur 「洋食焼き」って、たぶん関西弁ですねん。「一銭洋食」のことやと思います。薄っぺらいお好み焼きみたいな。

Comment: そうなんや、知らんかったわ。おおきに。関西の粉モン文化恐るべしやな。

Answer (score 10):

いい人 can be confusing if you don't know how to use it.

In a way, it can mean "good person".
But in this case it means "person who chooses XX". Especially during such votes.
It's in a way a very abridge and casual way to say :

> 「これ」の方がいいと思っている人はいますか？

It is also something me and probably many people do with their young children for fun. Ask "おいしい人！"、"もう一回やりたい人！"、"アイスクリームが食べたい人！", etc. and the kid will raise his hand with a big smile and say "はーい！"

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I am getting the context right, but could it be he was proposing two different alternatives and asking something like "Who's up for this? Who's up for that?"?

In this sense いい could be just meaning "good" in the sense of "be OK for". Like "For whom (人) is どど good (いい)?" And similarly in the other case.

So the point is that いい does not refer to 人 as in the sense of "good person", but rather "(In this group of people) who are the people for whom this or that kind of food is OK"?

Of course as I said, this depends on the context. As I interpreted it, one guy is asking to a group of friends questions and among these people some reply "hai" to the first while some other reply "hai" to the second (as if someone is taking votes to choose the most suitable option). If I got it wrong please let me know.

Comment: `I am not sure I am getting the context right``If I got it wrong` >> いえいえ。完璧だと思います＾＾

Answer (score 4):

In this case いい isn't a standalone part modifying 人. You can break it up as [洋食焼き"どど"がいい][人], or "people for whom [どど] is acceptable (say yes)."

Comment: I think this is the crucial point. Putting the brackets in makes it all make sense...

Answer (score -1):

"Objecct がいい人" stands for the asked person to prefer Object.
"いい" means like, good, prefer, want for asked friends on that situation.